# A smarter way of returning half a string instead of the full string in python (even strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a simple code for returning half a string instead of the full string
for example if the string is "Excellent" it should only return "exce".
My code works, but I was wondering if there was an easier, shorter way of doing this rather than mine which I feel may be a bit too long. Thank you

```
#Given a string of even length, return the first half. So the string "WooHoo" yields "Woo".

def first_half(str):
    new_L=len(str)//2
    new_str=""
    for i in range(new_L):
        new_str+=str[i]
    return new_str
```

Comment: Use a slice: `return str[:new_L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` values are sliceable:

```
def first_half(s):
    return s[:len(s)//2]
```

---

Building up a string one character at a time using `+` is extremely inefficient (you are constantly copying the accumulated string into a new `str` value). At the very least, you would want to use `str.join` instead:

```
def first_half(s):
    new_L = len(s) // 2
    return ''.join(s[i] for i in range(new_L))
```

but again, this is just duplicating what slicing already does.